# How can I create a LINQ expression that joins four tables and allows a where on the topmost table?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Topic
{
    public Topic()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}
public partial class SubTopic
{    
    public SubTopic()
    {
        this.Problems = new List<Problem>();
    }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

}
public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help tell me how I can construct a LINQ expression. What I need to do is to get just the QuestionId of the Questions that have a SubjectId = 0.

Here is a LINQ I created to get questions where the ProblemId was given:

```
var questions = _questionsRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(a => a.ProblemId == problemId)
        .ToList();
```

For this could someone tell me how I can make the LINQ expression join all the above tables so I can enter a SubjectId = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all the navigation properties needed, so you can just do :

```
var questions = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
.Where(m => m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 0)
.Select(m => m.QuestionId);
```

you may need some null check

```
.Where(m => m.Problem != null && 
            m.Problem.SubTopic ! null && 
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic != null &&
            m.Problem.SubTopic.Topic.SubjectId == 0)
.Select(m => m.QuestionId);
```